# I have tried to write a code to find if a word is a palindrome or not but it is not working. Whats's wrong with it?

Tags: c++, palindrome

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int len;
    char char1[100],char2[100];
    cout << "Enter a word:" << endl;

    cin >> char1;
    len = strlen(char1);

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        char2[i] = char1[len-i-1];
    }
    if(strcmp(char1,char2))
    {
        cout << "It is not a palindrome." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It is a palindrome" << endl;
    }
}
```

I have tried to write a code to find if a word is a palindrome or not. When I enter "madam" as input the output is "It is a palindrome". But when I enter "dad" as input the output is "It is not a palindrome". Why is it?

Comment: `char2` is missing a null-terminator, so it is not a valid C-style string

Comment: `strcmp` does not return a `bool` but an `int`. You should be comparing `strcmp` with 0, not 1

Comment: what is a null terminator?

Comment: Read up on how strings are represented in C and C++.  A string is represented as an array of `char`, with the last element having a numeric value zero (i.e. `'\0'`, not `'0'`).  That zero value is known by various names, such as a nul terminator or a sentinel (which indicates it marks the end).   Passing something to `strcmp()` which does not have that terminator gives undefined behaviour, since `strcmp()` ASSUMES that terminator is present.

Comment: I have tried  to "cout" the value that strcmp returns. It returns 1 or 0 or -1. so how can it give undefined behaviour.

Comment: Undefined behavior allows for any behavior, including "It returns 1 or 0 or -1.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because character arrays are used here to represent strings and also [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) is used to compare theses arrays, 
You need to remember that the last value of a text has to be `'\0'` (also called a null character / null terminator).

So after the loop, which copies the string in reverse, the following needs to be added;

```
char2[len] = '\0';
```

---

When using [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) the condition should be explicitly shown what it is checking. The reason is that `strcmp` returns 3 results (`-1`, `0` ,`1`) and from Your code it should be directly visible if the API is used correctly. (Even though C and C++ have an implicit conversion of a value to bool)

Also contrary to intuition the result of `strcmp` will be converted to `true` when the *compared strings are different* (`-1` and `1`) and converted to `false` when they *are the same* (`0`).

The condition should be, for example:

```
if (strcmp(char1, char2) == 0)    // checking if strings are equal
```

or

```
if (strcmp(char1, char2) != 0)    // checking if strings are different
```

In an ambiguous case of a function result like it is here, it is even suggested to create a temporary (constant) boolean variable to make the code easier to understand. Like this:

```
const bool is_palindrome = (strcmp(char1, char2) == 0);
if (is_palindrome)
    // ...
```

---

Here is another proposal, how to implement this algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "Enter a word:" << endl;

    string input_str;    
    getline(cin, input_str);

    const string reversed_str(input_str.rbegin(), input_str.rend());

    const bool is_palindrome = (input_str == reversed_str);

    if (is_palindrome)
    {
        cout << "It is a palindrome" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It is not a palindrome." << endl;
    }
}
```